# How to make battery balance charger for two 18650 batteries?

Tags: battery-balance

I am on a collage project, it requiring two 18650 li ion batteries. boost converter and solenoid lock mechanism requires can't operated through a single battery, and there is no balance charging module I found online, so how is it possible to charge them with tp4056 charging module? Or is there any other circuit/module or circuit diagram available to do that?, Thank you in advance with honours

Comment: Are the cells in series or parallel? Either way, to charge them you just need a constant current source at a suitable voltage, how you achieve that depends on so many things that we can't help without a lot more information.

Comment: I have tested both the batteries in series with solenoid and boost converter, but it is not working but both the batteries are chargeable I parallel with tp4056 module according to my knowledge and studies, but solenoid mechanism requires more voltage from batteries, I don't know why, as there is boost converter is connected already, solenoid mechanism is working only when batteries are connected in series and not in parallel, and the tp4056 can't charge 2 batteries and also I have not tested it as it makes 7.4V may not be suitable for tp4056, thank you with honours

Comment: Assuming Li-Ion cells in series at 4.5V charging voltage per cell (check your cell's datasheet before you take my word for it), you need a constant current source at 9V. A boost converter isn't going to be a constant current source unless it's designed to be, a standard boost converter will not charge the cells (it'll throw an over current error and shut down).

Comment: Sorry for lack of information, I'm using boost converter for solenoid, Current source/voltage source and power supply is not a problem but balance charging with they are connected in series and also circuit can handle load (if possible) at same time, thank you

Comment: Choose one of sollutions. 1) Use other charger for two litium battery. Ballancer is optional. 2) Use DC-DC step-up converter for solenoid.